# React Suspend: provide abort fetch cleanup

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense

Using the new React Suspend API, a promise can be thrown during component Render to tell Suspend to wait for that promise to complete before rendering the tree.

How can cancellation be provided so that if the Suspend component unmounts (e.g. parent component unmounts) all thrown promises will be interrupted?

Example: suspend throws a fetch, an abortcontroller should be signaled if suspense or component unmounts.